# How can I change the format value of the cells in a pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I am creating a pivot table in excel sheet by using vba code.
I want the values in the pivot  to be formatted as scientific with a symbol E,plus/minus sign and 2 decimal places.   e.g:  2.28E-10, 1.1E-09, 25E-3.

How do i reference cells within the Pivot table?
or shuold i reference them in the data source?

(my code takes data from sheet1 and creates another sheet named pivot,
 then creates the pivot)

so far:

```
Set rng = Range("b7:q9")     ' 

For Each cell In rng
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlAverage
     cell.NumberFormat = "#,##0" & "E-3"
Next cell
```

It does not work properly.

or maybe this one:

```
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim pff As PivotField
Dim pi  As PivotItem

With pff
    For Each pi In pff.PivotItems              
        pi.DataRange.NumberFormat = " 0.00#" & "E-3"               
        'pvt.DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "0.00#"
    Next pi
End With
```

Please suggest how to do this with vba.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to format all the values inside the `PivotTable` (I hope I understand what you meant to do), then you need to reference the values inside the `PivotTable` by using `pvt.DataBodyRange`.

Try the code below:

```
pvt.DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = " 0.00#" & "E-3"
```

---

**Edit 1**: to loop through the Pivot-Table's `DataBodyRange` cell by cell:

```
Dim PvtRng As Range, C As Range

Set PvtRng = pvt.DataBodyRange ' <-- set the Pivot Data range

For Each C In PvtRng ' loop cell by cell inside the Pivot-Table's DataBodyRange
    C.NumberFormat = " 0.00#" & "E-3"
Next C
```

Comment: If I understood correctly it does that all at once, the "pvt.DataBodyRange..." line and not cell after cell.     what if I want cell after cell?

Comment: @ofir cell by cell for all the values inside the Pivot Table ? What for ? Are there cells you will format another way ?

Comment: I need a cell by cell because I need to color them in green\red according to threshold .

Comment: and how you calculate the value of that cell?  I want  to multiply  each cell so i add the line:    C.Value = C.Value * 10 ^ 3    but c is a range and it doesn't  work

Comment: @ofir you can add a calculated field to your PivotTable

Comment: if i add calculated field it does it all at once and i want cell by cell

Comment: i want the numbers to be formatted with E-03 ,E-09 etc , so i need to manipulate each number in each cell. how can i do that in the above loop?

Comment: @ofir the best it to start a new post. Upload your latest code, share a screen-shot of your data, what you are trying to achieve, and I will gladly help.